# Nodejs - Angular, sending request to nodejs I get this error

Tags: node.js, angular-material

I'm getting this error in the browser:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://commapps.herokuapp.com/auth' from origin 'https://ecstatic-engelbart-897f34.netlify.app' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

I tried to set headers like this but did not work

```js
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');
  next();
});
```

Comment: If you'r using chrome then you might have to disable cors from you browser try to run it with firefox or any other browser once just to be confirm

Comment: When do you call this middleware?

Comment: I would also recommend understanding what CORS is if you are not clear on it, because its a safety measure deeply cooked into every modern web browser.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS if it is the firs time getting this error I gaurentee you it wont be the last.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use `cors` plugin available in express.

http://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html

```
var express = require('express');
var cors = require('cors');
var app = express();

app.use(cors());
```